# php array's first dimension is always equal to second one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

The Problem is $callback's first dimension never goes more than the length of second one.

for example if I add an other field like:
 `$callback[$counter]['field'] = $rec['filed'];`
both length will become 6.
how can i fix this?

```
public function returnAll(&$callback) {
    $callback = array();
    $counter  = 0;
    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE 1 ");
    $rec = $this->db->NextRecord();

    if (!($this->db->num_row() > 1))
        return false;

    while ( $rec ) {
        $callback[$counter]['title'] = $rec['title'];
        $callback[$counter]['text']  = $rec['text'];
        $callback[$counter]['type']  = $rec['type'];
        $callback[$counter]['abstract'] = $rec['abstract'];
        $callback[$counter]['news_date'] = $rec['news_date'];
        $rec = $this->db->NextRecord();

        $counter++;
    }

    return true;      
}
```

Comment: nope , I'm just trying to make everything from scrap , for learning issues.

Comment: Try placing the line $callback[$counter] = array(); to the front inside your loop.

Comment: Can you show an example of output (perhaps `print_r($callback);` before `return true;`) and tell us how it differs from what you expected? I'm not clear what the problem is from your description and code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, because your keys are the same you can just do:

```
$callback = array();
while($rec = $this->db->NextRecord()){
     $callback[] = $rec;
}
```